# PHP cURL - how to upload contents of a variable as a file via HTTP request?

Tags: php, curl, post, file-upload, php-curl

There are lots of answers to "upload file with php curl", and they all require that a physical file exists on the machine.  It's uploaded by referencing the @ symbol before the filename in the POST fields.

However, I have the file data already in a PHP variable: $data.  How can I upload this directly without needing to first write it to a file?

I tried this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => SERVER_URL . '/test.php?abc=def&ghi=jkl',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => ['file' => $data],
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ["Content-type: multipart/form-data"],
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => strlen($data)
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

But my server gives an error that POST Content-Length exceeds the server limit of 8388608 bytes.  However, in my php.ini file on the server, I have upload_max_filesize = 500M. So it looks like this POST is not being treated as a multipart file upload, but instead is trying to jam all the file data into the POST request.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could first write your string to a file in the /tmp folder. I'm not certain, but I think you might be required to do this if you want to post a file. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says :

> 7.0.0  Support for disabling the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option has been removed. All curl file uploads must use [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php).

EDIT: Please check the [docs on post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#post_max_size):

> **post_max_size** integer
>
> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than **upload_max_filesize**. Generally speaking, **memory_limit** should be larger than **post_max_size**...

Comment: I know I can write the data to a file... I was trying to avoid that extra step.  If it's not possible, I will do it. I just felt like I was missing something obvious.  Thanks

Comment: @RyanGriggs try adjusting your post_max_size value to something large enough to accommodate the file (or attempt a smaller test file) and see if it works. It just might -- although that "all curl file uploads must use CURLFile" warning for php 7.0.0 seems pretty ominous for forward-compatibility. You could also consider altering your script that handles the upload to accept the information as a string. You would probably want to base64 encode it to make sure it survives transit from curl to server.